# This dependency was not found: @/services/AuthenticationService

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use my AuthentifcationService in a Vue.js component

```
This dependency was not found:
* @/services/AuthenticationService in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Register.vue       

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @/services/AuthenticationService
```

Path structure: src->services.

AuthenticationService.js:

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
  register (credentials) {
    return Api().post('register', credentials)
  }
}
```

Register.vue

```
<script>
import AuthenticationService from '@/services/AuthenticationService'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async register () {
      const response = await AuthenticationService.register({
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      })
      console.log(response.data)
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you trying to use your function from `AuthenticationService`. But you can´t use it like a class and if you want to use it with `mixins`, you can´t call a function in  your component the same name, as it would be overwritten.

As a `mixin`, you could import it like that:

```
import AuthenticationService from '@/services/AuthenticationService'

data () {
    return {
        mixins: [AuthenticationService]
    }
}
```

Then you just call `register`. But note that if you import a function named `register` with `mixins` and there is also a function in your component named `register`, the imported function gets overwritten.